# how to set tilde + alias style?

Tags: bash, directory, tilde

I noticed there's default tilde + alias exist:

```
[root@xiaobai ~]# cd ~[press Tab]
~abrt/                ~dbus/                ~lp/                  ~openvpn/             ~root/                ~systemd-network/
~adm/                 ~ftp/                 ~mail/                ~operator/            ~rpc/                 ~systemd-resolve/
~apache/              ~games/               ~mpd/                 ~pkg-build/           ~rpcuser/             ~systemd-timesync/
~avahi/               ~gdm/                 ~mysql/               ~polkitd/             ~rtkit/               ~tcpdump/
~avahi-autoipd        ~geoclue/             ~nfs4user/            ~postfix/             ~saslauth/            ~toranon/
~bin/                 ~gnome-initial-setup  ~nfsnobody/           ~postgres/            ~shutdown/            ~tss
~chrony/              ~halt/                ~nm-openconnect/      ~pulse                ~sshd/                ~unbound/
~colord/              ~iguanair/            ~nobody/              ~qemu/                ~sync/                ~usbmuxd/
~daemon/              ~ldap/                ~ntop/                ~radvd/               ~systemd-bus-proxy/   ~xiaobai/
[root@xiaobai ~]# cd ~halt
[root@xiaobai sbin]# pwd
/sbin
[root@xiaobai sbin]# l ~halt
14 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8 Nov 18  2014 /sbin -> usr/sbin
[root@xiaobai sbin]# cd ~nobody/
[root@xiaobai //]# pwd
//
[root@xiaobai //]# 
[root@xiaobai //]# realpath ~nobody/
/
[root@xiaobai //]#
```

Where can i set this tilde+alias (i'm not talking about ~/.bashrc) ? Any reference/documentation about this combination ?

My platform is Fedora 21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's called [tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde), not 'tidle'.
2. They're not aliases, they're usernames on the system, when you press tab the shell is offering to auto-complete `~` to one of the user's home directories for you.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy,

> Create dummy entries in the /etc/passwd file with directory names, as
>   new user names, and append the right directory you want it to point
>   to. That's it.

***NOTE: Use different/unused UID, GID values***

Ex:

```
tomsawyer:x:402733:5762:tomsawyer,,,:/home/tomsawyer:/bin/bash
Desktop:x:999:999::/home/tomsawyer/Desktop/:/bin/bash
Downloads:x:999:999::/home/tomsawyer/Downloads/:/bin/bash
```

Here "tomsawyer" is an example real username, where as "Downloads" and "Desktop" are dummy usernames, and will be pointing to respective directories upon accessing with **"tilde notation"**